# Python how to count unique value by id from a csv file

Tags: python

I have the following csv file:

```
ID A
1 a
1 b
2 a
3 a
3 b
3 b
4 d
```

I want to count the unique value in column A by ID,

How do I get the output like this:

```
ID Unique_Count_A_by_ID
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 1
```

I have tried:

```
import csv

file = open('test.csv',newline='')
data = csv.reader(cfile)

ID_list=[]
for line in data:
    ID_list.append(str(line[0]))
 
unique_ID = list(set(ID_list))

count = []
for i in unique_ID:
    count.append(ID_list.count(i))
```

But this has nothing to do with column A. How do I link column A with ID so that I can get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with pandas dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('you_file.csv')

print(print(df.groupby('ID').agg({"A": "nunique"})))
```

---

Result:

```
ID
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` and `groupby`+`nunique`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.groupby('ID')['A'].nunique()
```

output:

```
ID
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    1
```